# Python Relative imports not working correctly

Tags: python, import

I'm building a large application, a game-engine if you so will. I've tried both relative and absolute imports but nothing seems to be working.[image: Relative import test]

As seen, I'm inside of Sacra/Screen/main.py and want to import something located in Sacra/Audio/PlayAudio.py; The part of which is a "simple" class.

To relate to the "problem", how can one do to import that class? I've looked through the bulk of python docs, real python and many more websites and all I get is the same, that it should be working as of right now.
Note: I've also tried ..Audio.PlayAudio import PlaySound, where PlaySound is the class in PlayAudio.
Another note: It's possbile to import in the Sacra, being a test.py file, with the code, import Audio. Because the init file is configuered.